# With what kind of IDE (if any) you build python GUI projects?

Tags: python, user-interface, ide

Is there any IDE (like VS) with drag and drop support for building python GUI, connecting to dbs etc?
Eventhough I am an emacs guy, I find it much easier to create GUI with VS.

Comment: See for example: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[python]+ide

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For GUI only, I find VisualWx (http://visualwx.altervista.org/) to be very good for designing wxPython apps under Windows.

For GUI + database, dabo (http://dabodev.com/) is probably a good answer.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is "no".  There is not a swiss-army-knife like IDE that is both a full-featured Python code-editor and a full-featured WYSIWYG GUI editor.  However, there are several stand-alone tools that make creating a GUI easier and there are a myriad of code editors, so if you can handle having two windows open, then you can accomplish what you are trying to.

As for stand-alone GUI editors, which you choose is going to depend on what library you choose to develop your GUI with.  I would recommend using [GTK+](http://www.gtk.org/), which binds to Python via [PyGtk](http://www.pygtk.org/) and has the [Glade](http://glade.gnome.org/) GUI designer.  I believe that there are other GUI libraries for Python that have WYSIWYG designers (Qt, Tkinter, wxWindows, etc.), but GTK+ is the one I have the most experience with so I will leave the others for other commentators.

Note, however, that the designer in this case is not at all language dependent.  It just spits out a .glade file that could be loaded into any language that has GTK+ bindings.  If you are looking for a designer that produces raw Python code (like the Code-Behind model that VS.Net uses), then I am not aware of any.

As for general code-editing IDE's (that do not include a GUI designer), there are [many](http://wiki.python.org/moin/IntegratedDevelopmentEnvironments), of which [PyDev](http://pydev.sourceforge.net/)/[Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) is probably the most Visual Studio-like.

(Revised for clarity.)

Comment: Wrong. See dabo for example.

Answer (score 4):

Also for PyGTK, there is [Gazpacho](http://gazpacho.sicem.biz/), it's pure python which makes adding your own custom widgets easier, and already has gtkbuilder support.

I took over maintenance of the project a few months ago, and we plan to release it under the umbrella of the [PIDA IDE](http://pida.co.uk/), in a more Visual Studio-like setup. Patches accepted!

Comment: Wow that is great to hear!  I had wondered what the status of Gazpacho was.  I would love to have a GTK editor available that supports gtkbuilder!  This might be the silver bullet that gets me using PIDA.

Comment: I took a look at gaspacho a while back. It doesn't look like it's had any updates for a while. Is the mercurial version the one that supports GtkBuilder?

Comment: Last release supports GtkBuilder, but there is no UI for turning it on/off.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really a Pythonista, but I *am* a Mac user and I appreciate a good, native interface in the apps I write and use. So, if I were to use Python for a GUI app on the Mac, I'd use PyObjC with Interface Builder and Xcode, rather than a cross-platform solution.

Answer (score 2):

If your into QT [EricIDE](http://die-offenbachs.de/eric/index.html) is a good choice

Answer (score 1):

[Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) has python support.

There's also [IDLE](http://www.python.org/idle/doc/idle2.html) or [Wingware](http://www.wingware.com/), though I'm not sure of their GUI support.

I'm sure a good [google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=python+ide) would turn up more.

But in the end, I doubt it.  Python is dependent on third-party widget sets like Qt, Tk, Gtk, wxWidgets, etc for GUI support.  Each of those will have their own system for laying things out.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Boa Constructor](http://boa-constructor.sourceforge.net/) or [Dabo](http://www.dabodev.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm a GNOME guy, so I prefer PyGTK. The standard GUI builder for that is the [Glade Interface Designer](http://glade.gnome.org/) (until it transitions to GtkBuilder).

Comment: Me too. Took me a bit to realize that the glade package in Ubuntu is obsolete, and the glade3 package is the up-to-date one. Beats me.

Answer (score 0):

For [wxPython](http://wxpython.org/) I use [xrced](http://xrced.sourceforge.net/) to make GUI definitions contained in xml files, I find this way to be elegant and scalable.

[wxformbuilder](http://wxformbuilder.org/) is also good.

As for the IDE, I'm a [WingIDE](http://www.wingware.com/) fan.